# How to call a class in Unity, without assigning the script to a gameObject

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have a gameController GameObject, which pulls in and creates 3 List objects built from text files (NameBoys, NameGirls, NameLast). I have defined a Name Class, which is defined as as 3 strings (first, middle, last). In the gameController GameObject, I want to create a function that returns an object of my custom Name type, which will then be used my a NPC type on screen unit. How can I reference the custom Name class in both the gameController GameObject as well as the NPC GameObject, without assigning the script to a gameObject and referencing the GameObject from both places?

Comment: **Don't write _about_** your code, **post it**.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have a script on gameController, which controlls your name class.
2. NPC should also have a script, with a field open to script of type gameController.
3. On NPC, you can reference this class (and any of it's contents) by dragging the class on gameController onto the script on NPC.

---

**Notes:**

- NPC will have all data gameController has, updated every frame

Comment: This won't work, at least now the way I'm hoping. I won't be able to define a variable in the NPC script using the Type name from the gameController object's name class.

Comment: @JacobMueller I am having a hard time understanding you. Could you explain what you mean by "using the Type name from gameController object's name class"? Thanks

Comment: I have 3 csv's, girl's names, boys names, and last names. They're fairly large. Rather than turn those into a List inside each one of a bunch of NPCs that will use those lists to randomly create a name, I put that functionality in a GameControllerObject, so once on initial load, those csv's are turned into Lists, and then I can call the function to return an object that uses those CSV's to return a custom class that has a first, middle, and last name. How can I use the custom class 'Name' that exists in the Game controller object, in the NPC object, without recoding the class in both places?

Comment: @JacobMueller I am a little confused by what you mean "recording the class in both places".

Comment: I didn't say 'recording', I said 'recoding'. Attempting to explain myself to you, however, showed me the answer. Thanks for your time and response.

Comment: @JacobMueller Oh, ok lol

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to explain my issue to Walter showed me the answer. Just add a namespace to your custom class, and you can reference it normally like you would in any other C#.net application, with a 'using' clause.